XPath 1.0 sum and decimal places
I have various xml nodes which contain integers, like the below which are pulled into a Word document based off variables within the XML file.
<example>0</example>
<example>2</example>
<example>0</example>
<example>1</example>

I am currently using the following to count the values of the nodes, not the nodes themselves, in order to get a total count of the values, in this case the answer output is 3.
sum(//project[1]/example[*]/total_examples[text()])
However, when the document is produced, the above XPath is output as '3.0' instead of '3'.
I initially tried a translate of:
translate(sum(...), '.0','')
however this also translated, and removed any outputs where all the values totalled to 0.
I have also tried floor(...) which still produced the decimal place.
Is there anyway to strip out just the decimal place from this output? I don't have access to the XML file as its auto generated so cannot use XSLT variables or similar.
Pure XPath1.0 query only.
If this is not possible, is there a way to do something like:
if total_examples != 0 
   //strip the .0
   translate(sum(//project[1]/example[*]/total_examples[text()]), '.0', '')

EDIT:
Thanks for the replies.
round() - still prints out 3.0
any form of substring-before, including converting to a string before and after substring-before, does not print anything, or gives NaN using the below.
round(substring-before(sum(//project[1]/example[*]/total_examples[1]), "."))
Guess the processor doesn't conform to usual XML rules. Will have to stick with the decimal for now, I guess.

You could use fn:format-number() with a decimal format to control how the numbers are formatted and ensure that it does not have .0.
fn:format-number(sum(//project[1]/example[*]/total_examples[text()]), '#')


unfortunately with this I get 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed', of which I cannot add this as the xml doc is auto generated.

remove fn: and see if it works for you. What XSLT processor are you using?

With 1.0, format-number is available only in XSLT, not in XPath.

You could use substring-before() and select the text before the ".":
substring-before(sum(//project[1]/example[*]/total_examples[text()]), ".")


The result of your XPath expression is a number, not a string, and you don't say how you are converting the number to a string (which is presumably in your calling application).
Try doing the conversion within XPath itself, using the string() function. A conformant processor should output the result as "3", not "3.0". If you're using a non-conformant processor, then I can't help you.

You could use the round() function:
round(sum(//project[1]/example[*]/total_examples[text()]))

